# Emscripten and web views for GUI in a game

Tags: c++, user-interface, awesomium, emscripten

I am a C++ programmer and my friend is a web programmer, we want to make a simple game with rendering being done in C++/OpenGL ES 2.0 and the GUI be displayed through a web view.

We are using Emscripten to display C++ code in a browser, should we use Awesomium and compile it with Emscripten or something? or is there another way since we are already compiling javascript from LLVM.

An easy solution would be very appreciated,

Thanks